# How to compare a string with a python enum?

Tags: python, enums, python-3.6

I just discovered the existence of an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) base class in python and I'm trying to imagine how it could be useful to me.

Let's say I define a traffic light status:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Signal(Enum):
    red = auto()
    green = auto()
    orange = auto()
```

Let's say I receive information from some subsystem in my program, in the form of a string representing a colour name, for instance `brain_detected_colour = "red"`.

**How do I compare this string to my traffic light signals?**

Obviously, `brain_detected_colour is Signal.red` is `False`, because `Signal.red` is not a string.

`Signal(brain_detected_colour) is Signal.red` fails with `ValueError: 'red' is not a valid Signal`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

One does not create an [instance of an Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum-members-aka-instances).
The `Signal(foo)` syntax is used to access Enum members by value, which are not intended to be used when they are `auto()`.

However one can use a string to [access Enum members](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) like one would access a value in a `dict`, using square brackets:

```
Signal[brain_detected_colour] is Signal.red
```

Another possibility would be to compare the string to the `name` of an Enum member:

```
# Bad practice:
brain_detected_colour is Signal.red.name
```

But here, we are not testing identity between Enum members, but comparing strings, so it is better practice to use an equality test:

```
# Better practice:
brain_detected_colour == Signal.red.name
```

(The identity comparison between strings worked thanks to [string interning](http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/), which is better not to be relied upon. Thanks @mwchase and @Chris_Rands for making me aware of that.)

Yet another possibility would be to explicitly set the member values as their names when creating the Enum:

```
class Signal(Enum):
    red = "red"
    green = "green"
    orange = "orange"
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785241/1878788) for a method to have this automated.)

Then, `Signal(brain_detected_colour) is Signal.red` would be valid.

Comment: Using `is` in `brain_detected_colour is Signal.red.name` is risky; it'd be better to use `==`.

Comment: @mwchase Could you explain why, so that I can edit my answer and add an explanation?

Comment: You're relying on string interning, murky implementation details http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/, never use `is` unless you actually need to compare the identity of the objects

Comment: Solved my problem. Though I could not use `Signal(brain_detected_colour) is Signal.red` (mentioned at the end of the answer, for when an enum is built with string values)... `Signal[brain_detected_colour] == Signal.red` does work however. Note that I took into account the comment saying that using `==`for the comparison is less risky.

Comment: Yes, i had the same issue when comparing an enum value with a string, although they had the same string value, with "is" it did not work, using == solved my problems

Comment: To save other people searching, note that `a is b` is syntactic sugar for `id(a) == id(b)`

Answer (score 81):

A better practice is to inherit `Signal` from `str`:

```py
class Signal(str, Enum):
    red = 'red'
    green = 'green'
    orange = 'orange'

brain_detected_colour = 'red'
brain_detected_colour == Signal.red  # direct comparison
```

Comment: Can you explain in the answer, why this is a better practice?

Comment: Just in case you are still interested on knowing why is better to use the mixin str
https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#others

Comment: This worked for me. @MartinGrey that might be because you comparing a `string`  type with and `enum` type. I was having probelm comparing string with enum when `str` was not present in enum class. (assigning string values was not enough, i guess.)

Comment: Shouldn't you use `.value` (e.g. `Signal.red.value`) when comparing?

Comment: @OlimjonIbragimov You need to do that when you're using a normal `Enum`. But when you mix-in `str` for example: `class Signal (str, Enum):`, then you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 34):

It is possible to have `auto()` return the name of the enum member as its value (which is in the [`auto` section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values)<sup>1</sup>:

```
class AutoName(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name

class Ordinal(AutoName):
    NORTH = auto()
    SOUTH = auto()
    EAST = auto()
    WEST = auto()
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Ordinal)
[<Ordinal.NORTH: 'NORTH'>, <Ordinal.SOUTH: 'SOUTH'>, <Ordinal.EAST: 'EAST'>, <Ordinal.WEST: 'WEST'>]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This requires version Python 3.6, or `aenum` 2.0<sup>2</sup> (`aenum` works with Pythons as old as 2.7).

<sup>2</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Unfortunately though the following assert fails: `assert Ordinal.NORTH == "NORTH"` so you can't directly compare to a string.
Edit: oh, this can work by using `class Ordinal(str, AutoName)`.

Comment: Would you mind editing the code so that it's copy-pastable?

Answer (score 2):

```py
class Signal(Enum):
    red = auto()
    green = auto()
    orange = auto()

    def equals(self, string):
       return self.name == string

brain_detected_colour = "red"

if Signal.red.equals(brain_detected_colour):
   #something awesome
```